# How to deal with mutations of a fixed date?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

The [`.add()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) method of `moment.js`

> Mutates the original moment by adding time.

```
var now = moment([2015, 11, 29, 14]);
var tomorrow = now.add(1, 'd');
// now has changed
```

**What is the correct approach if I have a fixed 'now' moment which I would like to reuse later in my program?**

The best I found is a construction like

```
var ref = [2015, 11, 29, 14];
var now = moment(ref);
var tomorrow = moment(ref).add(1, 'd');
var start = moment(ref).startOf('day'); // beginning of today
var end = moment(ref).add(1, 'd').endOf('day'); // end of tomorrow
```

but it looks clumsy to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From their docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/):

> Note: It should be noted that moments are mutable. Calling any of the manipulation methods will change the original moment.
>
> If you want to create a copy and manipulate it, you should use moment#clone before manipulating the moment. [More info on cloning](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/moment-clone/).

```
var now = moment([2015, 11, 29, 14]);
var tomorrow = now.clone().add(1, 'd');
var start = now.clone().startOf('day'); // beginning of today
var end = now.clone().add(1, 'd').endOf('day'); // end of tomorrow
```

A [quick look at their code on Github](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/moment.js) shows that all they do there is `return new Moment(this)`, so you could do the same thing by doing `new Moment(now)` instead of `now.clone()` if that's more clear to you. I personally think you should use whatever method seems the most clear to you.